# cakephp url validation

Tags: validation, cakephp

One of my models has a 'url' field. I am using the default url validation rule on it. When trying to add a specific url it is not validated.

The url causing validation to fail is http://careers2.hiredesk.net/ViewJobs/JobDetail.asp?Comp=I3&TP_ID=1&PROJ_ID={BDA01FCD-5703-4D40-9197-CCF688633951}

The `{` character is causing the validation to fail. What workarounds do I have here?

Comment: That's simply because `{` in a url makes an invalid url, so of course it should invalidate :) Even if you were to make it "valid" the url wouldn't be valid as far as the RFC is concerned. That said, you could create your own validation rule using regex to validate the way you want.

Comment: can you give me an example of the appropriate regex expression or point me somewhere where can I get more info about regex?

Comment: I don't know what an appropriate regex would be because I don't know your parameters. Google has a lot to offer. Say you want just alphanumeric, try "regex alphanumeric" or "regex alphanumeric with special symbols" and remove the symbols you don't need. It's a very specialized (but not outlined) request.

Answer (score -2):

Do you pass your given URL through a [URL Encode Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) first? See the linked page for an example.

Comment: This should likely be a comment.